# Equivalence between IVP and integral equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, initial-value-problems

I was trying to prove the following theorem: If $f(x, y)$ is continuous on some region $R \subseteq \mathbb R^2$ then any solution of IVP $$y'(x)=f(x,y(x)), y(x_0)=y_0 \tag{1}$$ is also a solution of integral equation $$y(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(t,y(t)) \, dx \tag{2}$$ Converse also holds, meaning that, any continuous solution of $(2)$ is also a solution of $(1)$.

Proof: Let $\varphi$ be the solution of $(1)$ on some interval $\mathcal I$ which contains point $x_0$. Than we have $$\varphi'(t)=f(t,\varphi(t)),\forall t\in\mathcal I\tag{3}$$ and $$\varphi(x_0)=y_0\tag{5}$$ We would like for the right hand side of $(3)$ to be Riemman integrable, and it would be, provided that $f(t,\varphi(t))$ is continuous. Then we could simply integrate relation $(3)$ and obtain $$\int_{x_0}^x \varphi'(t) \,dt=\int_{x_0}^x f(t,\varphi(t)) \,dt \tag{6}$$ which would yield, after evaluating left integral $$\varphi(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(t,\varphi(t)) \,dt,\forall x\in\mathcal I \tag{7}$$This would mean that $\varphi$ is indeed a solution of $(2)$ which would complete proof in one direction. Problem here lies in continuity of function $f(t,\varphi(t))$ on $\mathcal I$. $\varphi$ is continuous on $\mathcal I$ for sure because it's differentiable on $\mathcal I$ as given by $(3)$. Also by $(3)$ we know that for every $t\in\mathcal I$, point $(t,\varphi(t))$ belongs to domain of $f(x,y)$, but not necessarily the set $R$ for which we know that $f(x,y)$ is continuous on. How can we then guarantee continuity of $f(x,y)$ on $\mathcal I$ without additional assumptions like $$Dom(f(x,y))=R\tag{8}$$ or weaker one $\forall t\in\mathcal I:(t,f(t))\in R\tag{9}$ Do we have to introduce $(8)$ or $(9)$ into the statement of the theorem? Proving converse goes something like this, at least in all of the references that I could find:

Let $\varphi$ be the continuous solution of $(2)$ on some interval $\mathcal I$ which contains point $x_0$. Than we have $$\varphi(x)=y_0+\int_{x_0}^x f(t,\varphi(t)) \, dx,\forall t\in\mathcal I\tag{10}$$ Now we would like to differentiate relation $(10)$. By the FTC, if $f(t,\varphi(t))$ is continuous on $\mathcal I$, then $\int_{x_0}^x f(t,\varphi(t)) \, dx$ is differentiable on $\mathcal I$ and it holds that $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x_0}^x f(t,\varphi(t)) \, dx=f(x,\varphi(x))\tag{11}$$ So by differentiation of $(10)$ we obtained  $$\varphi'(x)=f(x,\varphi(x)),\forall x\in\mathcal I\tag{12}$$Also, after plugging $x_0$ into $(10)$ we get $\varphi(x_0)=y_0$, and this would mean that $\varphi$ is a solution to an IVP $(1)$. Still, problem with continuity of $f(x,y)$ remains. $\varphi$ is continuous on $\mathcal I$ and $f(x,y)$ is continuous on some region $R$. As I see it, their composition can be continuous on $\mathcal I$ only if $(8)$ or $(9)$ holds. Maybe I am missing something and continuity of $f$ can be deduced by other means? I feel like learning this by heart without understanding its core would do me no good so in that case I would be better of studying poetry instead of math. Thanks to whoever read the whole thing and has any idea about this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing Cauchy-Lipschitz or Picard-Lindelof theorem for the ODE, which usually assumes that that $ f \in \mathcal{C}([0,T] \times \mathbb{R}) $ in addition to being Lipschitz continuous in the second argument. Here I assume $x_0=0$ for convenience and $T>0$. Then you use your proof to equate the integral solution and the ODE and use Banach fixed point to guarantee a solution for $0 < t\leq T$. 
There is a local version of this theorem which says that given any $r>0$ if $ f \in \mathcal{C} \left( [0,T] \times \overline{B(y_0;r)} \right)$ and $f$ is Lipschitz continuous in the second argument then the ODE admits a unique solution for $0 < t\leq \tau$ for some $\tau \in (0,T]$. Here $\overline{B(y_0;r)}$ is the closed ball centered at $y_0$ with radius $r$.  
This works because the function $t \rightarrow f(t,\varphi(t)) $ is clearly continuous in a neighborhood of $x_0$ since $f$ is continuous in a neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of Picard theorem about existence and uniqueness. As a matter of fact we are required to prove it using theorem I posted, so we cannot really use any assumptions made in Picard-Lindelof theorem or Peano theorem as it would be circular reasoning.

Comment: Not sure I'm understanding your point. Your proof only shows that the IVP is equivalent to the integral problem. But to prove existence and uniqueness you need Banach fixed point theorem (applied to the integral problem) which is the content of Picard Lindelof theorem. In any case, as I mentioned in the post if you assume $f \in \mathcal{C} \left( [0,T] \times \overline{B(y_0;r)}   \right)$ for some $r>0$ you solve your problem of continuity of the function $t \rightarrow f(t,\varphi(t))$.